# How to run GATE/JAPE for non English language?

Tags: java, nlp, jnlp, gate

I would like to use JAPE/GATE to my own mother language (not English), as my documents are already tokenized and POS Tag. 
So how can I let GATE load my documents as resource for processing?

Comment: GATE currently supports English, Spanish, Chinese, Arabic, Bulgarian, French, German, Hindi, Italian, Cebuano, Romanian, Russian. Is your language one of these? If so, what prevents you from using GATE? Can you be more specific and tell what error message(s) you get?

Comment: In what format are your documents and annotations (tokens, POS tags, etc.) stored? Post some short example please.

Answer (score 0):

You have more detailed about GATE format here: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch5.html#x8-1030005.5

Moreover, GATE accept the CoNLL file format which looks like that:

```
Rockwell NNP
said VBD
the DT
agreement NN
```

You can try this sample with the `.conll` extension.

Good luck